# ViewPager: Fire event before page change

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm using Android Studio 1.2.1.1 and I've implemented a ViewPager with a fair few fragments. I'm trying to get the data from each of the fragments into a public class via an interface. The classa nd interface are not the issue though, I want to export the data from the current page before a new page is selected, unfortunately it appears these are the only options and none really suit my needs:

```
    _mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int position) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        }

    });
```

I would be able to invoke the call to export the data easily on checkboxes etc, but my fragments include imageviews (exported as base64) and edittexts. Has anyone else come across this in the past? Is it an easy one or is it going to be changing my code entirely?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: "I want to export the data from the current page before a new page is selected" -- that makes no sense IMHO. By definition, every microsecond the `ViewPager` exists is "before a new page is selected". We have no way of predicting exactly when a user will switch to a new page.

Comment: Ok, forgive my terminology. When the user slides another fragment into view, I want to export the data from the fragment that is being removed from visibility. Pretty much every other action I've come across in Android Studio allows a 'before' statement, however I cannot seem to find one for ViewPager.

Comment: What I do normaly in situations like this. I place all my data in app context with is available for every activity and fragment. Let every fragment work on the data in app context, and use the lifecycle of the fragment to catch the data you need. This way you dont need to handle this in a onPageChangeListener.

Comment: "I want to export the data from the fragment that is being removed from visibility" -- so, do that in `onPageSelected()`.

Comment: Thanks Rene M, i'll look into this

Comment: Doesn't OnPageSelected only fire when the new page is being brought into view? Therefore I will lose reference to the now-invisible fragment?

Comment: @ReneM. Do you know how the memory is handled with this approach? With my current approach I can wipe the data and reference once the data from my fragments has been compiled. Can the reference be destroyed in the app context? I'm new to all this so please forgive me if I am asking stupid questions. Edit: I've also set the offscreenPageLimit to 25, so I don't think I'll be able to use the lifecycle to extract the data.

Comment: The benefit is that the app context has its own lifecycle which spans over the lifetime of the app. Yes you can add, remove and change data in there as you like. I don't think that you have that much data in your app that it causes ram problems handling them in the app context. Anyway also when you are handling 1gig of data you could serialize it in the app context if needed to reduce used ram.

Comment: Thanks again @ReneM. I will read up a bit more before attempting this I think

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just keep a reference to what page you're currently on and set that index every time onPageSelected is called. You can then see what the index was before changing it and update the old Fragment with that?

Example:

```
int oldPosition = -1;

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                if (oldPosition != -1) {
                     extractInformationFromFragment(oldPosition);
                }
                oldPosition = position;
            }

private void extractInformationFromFragment(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment1.getInformation();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment2.getInformation();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment3.getInformation();
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Thanks vguzzi, that looks simple enough for my wee brain to implement, I'll give it a go

Comment: In response to your question in the other comments (I haven't got 50 rep yet can't comment in there). onPause is called in each Fragment only when you have scrolled two pages away from it, so you will be able to access the fragment you are currently viewing and the fragments to the left and right of that (if they are fragments there). So the above code should be able to extract data from each Fragment successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I'm handling it this way :

```
private int mCurrentSelectedPage = 0;

    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(mTabLayout) {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            super.onPageSelected(position);
            // Get data from last selected fragment
            EditFragment oldFragment = getFragment(mCurrentSelectedPage);
            if (oldFragment != null) {
               oldFragment.getData();
            }
            // Set data to the new fragment
            EditFragment newFragment = getFragment(position);
            if (newFragment != null) {
                newFragment.setData();
            }
            mCurrentSelectedPage = position;
        }
    });


public EditFragment getFragment(int position) {
    String fragmentTag = "android:switcher:" + mViewPager.getId() + ":" + position;
    return (EditFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag);
}
```